# Am I lame? (Riley riddle)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I'm trying to make a good Riley riddle, but this is my first time, so please tell me if this is good or where I can improve on.

The riddle goes like this:

> The prefix is just before you,
>
> The suffix rolls before you.
>
> The infix sounds like a female name,
>
> And with the word you don't care whether I'm lame.

Hint 1:

> The answer is not a name.

Hint 2:

> The answer can be a noun and a verb.

Hint 3:

> The prefix can be found in the riddle and this hint.

Comment: I feel like the first and second are dogs…

Comment: Mamma Mia..  Lili'ANNA

Comment: Just a note, when giving hints, be sure to wait for quite a while (like a few hours or even a day) as there are many users with different time zones that haven't seen your question yet :D @OmegaKrypton

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on @AHKieran answer I would think that the answer is

> Prejudice

Prefix

> Pre is in the hint and just standing in the first lane before us

Infix

> Judi (maybe even Judice) sounds like a female name

Suffix

> Thanks to @AHKieran dice that you role in front of you.

And with the word you don't care whether I'm lame.

> prejudice 'preconceived opinion that is not based on reason or actual experience.' -> it's your opinion so you don't care if it's incorrect or lame.

Comment: Good spot! Glad I helped :)

Comment: Nice job! You got it!

Answer (score 5):

Partial:

Prefix:

> I think the prefix is T/Te/Tea, it says "just before you", I took this to mean "just before U" in the alphabet, which is the letter T.

Infix:

> I imagine the infix is a female name with a different spelling, not sure which.

Suffix:

> Perhaps the suffix is dice or die? As you roll them in front of you when playing a game.

Comment: You got the suffix right, but not the prefix and the infix. Keep it up!